# Authenticate user with Prestashop WebService

Tags: prestashop

I need to develop iOS and Android apps for e-commerce site powered by Prestashop. Is it possible to authenticate users with the help of WebService?

Comment: Hey @torayeff did you get the solution on this ?

Comment: @Arjit unfortunately